# Intuition behind nloglikelihood value in xgboost poisson run

Tags: python, xgboost, poisson, gbm

When I am using `count:poisson` instead of `rmse` I am seeing `nloglikelihood` values. Now I am not sure how to compare those numbers with rmse or mae.

Definitely lesser the value better .. but not getting actual error intuition that we get with rmse or Mae.

For example -> `train-poisson-nloglik:2.01885   val-poisson-nloglik:2.02898`

Here can we say, actual values differ by 2.02 error.
Can someone explain with small example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good post on the computation of the value [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262469/poisson-deviance-xgboost-vs-gbm-vs-regression)

Just to be more exhaustive, the value is:

```
mean(factorial(label) + preds - label*log(preds))
```

If you compare with the true formula of the negative log-likelihood, it should be the `sum` instead of the `mean`. I guess that they choose to take the mean so that the train and the test values are more comparable.

Finally, to answer the question, the likelihood is the probability that the data came from the distribution with a specific parameter. In the Poisson model, the parameters are just the set of predictions. So the better is your prediction, the greater is the probability, the smaller is the associate negative log-likelihood.

`rmse` or `mae` are based on the expectation of the difference between the prediction and the truth whereas negative log-likelihood is looking at a probability.